# $_GET variable not showing up in string and boolean operations

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, variables, post

I have a javascript file that uses POST to send some data to a PHP file, as such:

```
var additional = "Feb2015";
xmlhttp.open("POST", "database_comm_general.php?query=" + additional, true);
```

In the PHP file, I use $_GET to get that 'additional' variable:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
```

Now, if I want to use it to get some data from MySql, I use this for my query, but when I echo it, it just shows empty quotation marks, where 'Feb2015' should be:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM '" . $query . "'";
Output: "SELECT * FROM ''"
```

Even more odd, if I use json_encode and print it on the javascript side, it shows up just fine.

Similarly, if I see if the variable equals 'Feb2015', with json_encode it will return true, but on the page it will output false at the same time.

Any ideas?

Edit:

This is my javascript code:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var content = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        window.alert(content);}}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "database_comm_general.php?query=" + additional, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: That looks like a terrible terrible thing to do.. HOWEVER. You're sending a POST, not a GET. You should be using $_POST, rather than $_GET.

Comment: `json_encode and print it on the javascript side` Thing at that point everbody get stuck. What do you mean with that? And show more of your code.

Comment: Add this to your php code, just to confirm that you're actually receiving a value in $_GET:  file_put_contents('get_array.txt', print_r($_GET, TRUE));  Then, execute the javascript and view the file.

Comment: @Farkie, using $_POST gives me null in all instances. Could you elaborate on why it is terrible? I read it was the best way to communicate between javascript and PHP.

Comment: @JOUM I added an edit with javascript code, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @Craig The file reads: Array ( [query] => Feb2015 ), so I am receiving it. Also, thank you for that, I am new to PHP and that little piece of code will help me in the future.

Comment: Test all part in single. Run `database_comm_general.php?query=Feb2015` directly in your browser and look what is coming, and only valid json has to return there, with the information u want. Test also `var_export($_REQUEST)` and see what coming to php. and last: use F12 Browser developer-console-(tab)network and look what javascript does send and recive when is call the php file from javascript.

Comment: @JOUM Running directly in browser returns 'Feb2015', var_export($_REQUEST) returns an empty array, with the console I am not sure what I should be looking for. All I see is things are executed in the correct order.

Comment: You can click on the ajax-url in the browser dev-nav-tab too get mor information. `Running directly in browser returns 'Feb2015'` so something within PHP must go wrong after you  bind the value to `$query`. `print $query;` shows what? Right after `$query = $_GET['query'];`  and right before `$sql_query =`?

Comment: Why im asking because you say `showing up in string and boolean operations` and there is no php code that does any operation. You have too show more from that. But im out sry its late here.

Comment: @tau, glad to hear it's passing the get array.  So...in your original post, you say that 'when I echo [the sql string], it just shows empty quotation marks, where 'Feb2015' should be'...how are you doing this?  Are you calling the php from a browser and it's displaying the string in your browser?

Comment: @JOUM It shows fine with print. Yes, I may have included too little code still. I was trying to avoid confusion with unrelated code. I'll do some more work and testing tomorrow, as it is also late here, and if I make no progress, I'll post the entire code here.

Comment: @Craig The javascript code in the edit is contained within another php file - navigation_page.php. Since I use include for the php file I'm having problems with, it is both displaying the string on the page and returning it to window.alert in javascript when I use echo. I'll restructure the code tomorrow and if it's not fixed, I'll upload the entire code for both files. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's no way a variable can have a value in one line of code, and then no value in a later line of code, unless you overwrote the variable or changed variable scopes (e.g. you're building the query down inside a function). You need to show a FULL example of the non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I haven't been able to fix this exact issue, but I got my code working through other means:

First, I use jquery instead of javascript for communicating with PHP:

```
text = "Feb2015";
$.ajax(
    { url : "database_comm_general.php?" + text, success: function(data){
        var return_data = JSON.parse(data);
        populateTableList(return_data);
    }});
```

Second, in the PHP file, I don't use $_GET, I get the data from the link address:

```
$link = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$index = strpos($link, "?");
$sub_string = substr($link, $index+1, 7);
$sub_string = $sub_string;
```

Third, I added a single line of code in the MySQL code that resolved the issues with some of the arrays which couldn't be encoded:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
```

All in all, I feel I've been to hell and back, but I hope this helps someone in the future.